# Synergy server will not connect on setup

Tags: windows-7, synergy

Trying to get past the server set up part getting following response:

```
Unable to install uninstall service: Error code 1
```

I get a popup box with the following text:

```
2011-04-13T14:06:02 FATAL: Init failed: Access is denied.
Try `synergys.exe --help' for more information.
..\lib\synergy\CApp.cpp,275
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes - this is a common problem with Synergy in Win 7.

The answer is simple - you need to run the configuration routine as the Administrator.

Right click on the qsynergy in the start menu, and select "Run as Administrator".  Then you will be able to start the service.